# Multiple table having foreign keys on single

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have database with couple of tables. All tables have foreign key to single one. Now, I'read about data warehouse and star schema and I'm wondering is it better to leave it like it is, or should I put this foreign keys in that single table and from thar referencing other tables (which is opposite from current state)?.
Which approach is better, to have single table having FK on many others, or  to have many other tables having FK on single one?

Answer (score 1):

A data warehouse is typically abstracted from an existing relational database, i.e. you should have a functioning, well-designed relational database before you start building your data warehouse. Don't convert your single DB into a DW, it's gonna be a pain and I can guarantee you it won't work, best to leave them to their own environment.

And the way a typical data warehouse works is the (single) fact table contains all the foreign keys and 'facts', that reference the primary keys in the dimension tables.

Comment: A DW can include more than one star, with more than one fact table.  In some cases, dimension tables can be used in more than one star.  I agree that converting the single DB into a DW is probably a mistake.